# How to speed up sending big file to Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am very new to databases. So I am trying to send my transformers hugging face model to google cloud by doing this

```
model_file = pickle.dumps(model)

blob = bucket.blob(f"models/{user_id}.pickle")

blob.upload_from_string(model_file)
```

I am getting this error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

I have tried using zlib to compress it and speed it up however it still doesnt work.

Any help would be appreciated it thanks.

Comment: You don't have a speed issue, but a connection issue. Fix the communication first, then sniff your network bandwidth to see it it is at capacity. If no, you could investigate to improve the speed (multipart upload for instance

Comment: Hello, been trying to fix the connection however all options not working. Do u have any reccomendations?

Comment: What's the current status?